# how to get data from another table without joining in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to get the name of the product, but keeping the same amount of sales, when joining, I only get 1 record, but I want to get the 3 sales records

Products

[image: this is my sales chart]
Sales

[image]

my sql query

```
SELECT p.name as 'Descripción', p.cost as 'Precio de costo',p.price as 'Precio de venta',
sum((p.price-ps.discount)+(ps.discount/ps.qty)) as 'precio con descuento', ps.discount as 'descuento', ps.qty as 'cantidad',
ps.total as 'Sub total venta', (sum((p.price-ps.discount)+(ps.discount/ps.qty))-p.cost)/ps.qty as 'Utilidad',
sum((p.price-ps.discount)+(ps.discount/ps.qty))-p.cost as 'Sub Total Utilidad'
FROM product_sales ps
inner join products p on p.id = ps.product_id
```

This is the result I wish to obtain,
3 records instead of 1.

[image]

Comment: What's your expected result and could you provide text format data instead of image thanks.

Comment: Add a picture of the result you want to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the aggregation function `SUM()` since you are not aggregating over the rows of the results.
Also you must calculate the column `Sub total venta` correctly:

```
SELECT 
  p.name as `Descripción`, 
  p.cost as `Precio de costo`,
  p.price as `Precio de venta`,
  (p.price-ps.discount)+(ps.discount/ps.qty) as `precio con descuento`, 
  ps.discount as `descuento`, 
  ps.qty as `cantidad`,
  p.price * ps.qty - ps.discount as `Sub total venta`, 
  (((p.price-ps.discount)+(ps.discount/ps.qty))-p.cost)/ps.qty as `Utilidad`,
  (p.price-ps.discount)+(ps.discount/ps.qty)-p.cost as `Sub Total Utilidad`
FROM product_sales ps INNER JOIN products p 
ON p.id = ps.product_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query would be invalid in most databases and in the most recent version of MySQL.  Why?  It is missing the `GROUP BY`.  This is an aggregation query because you have `SUM()`, but I don't think it is necessary.

I would advise you to simply fix your query:

```
SELECT p.name as Descripción, p.cost as `Precio de costo`,
       p.price as `Precio de venta`,
       ((p.price-ps.discount)+(ps.discount/ps.qty)) as `precio con descuento`,
       ps.discount as `descuento`, ps.qty as 'cantidad',
       ps.total as `Sub total venta`,
       ((p.price-ps.discount)+(ps.discount/ps.qty))-p.cost)/ps.qty as Utilidad,
       ((p.price-ps.discount)+(ps.discount/ps.qty))-p.cost as `Sub Total Utilidad`
from product_sales p join
     products p
     on p.id = ps.product_id ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove all occurrences of SUM from your statement. This is an aggregation function which will sum the values of all rows and return one row.

columnA + columnB will give you the sum of two columns in the same row.

Answer (score 0):

CREATE VIEW in MYSQL and use it again and again with the simple SELECT query

`CREATE VIEW view_name AS
SELECT column1, column2, ...
FROM table_name
JOIN table_name ON condition
WHERE condition;`

Reference link of [MySQL CREATE VIEW](https://w3tpoint.com/php/mysql-create-view)